# Find all nodes with two-way relationships starting from one specific node using cypher in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[neo4j nodes and relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHB2k.png)

This is quite a tough job. I'm trying to find all nodes with two-way relationships starting from a specific node. Based on the image above, I would like to find all two-way relationships starting from node 1. Only nodes with two-way relationships match. For example, node 1,3,4 matches and node 1,2,3 matches as two separate groups. However, if node 2 and 4 has a two-way relationship, then node 1,2,3,4 matches as one group. The main idea is that all nodes are linked both ways in such a group. My idea is to find all nodes with two-way relationships starting from 1 and continue processing, but I'm not able to continue. Can anyone help me with this problem, thanks a lot. By the way, only the largest 'two-way-circle' is needed.

Comment: Any one can help? So difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks a lot like finding strongly connected components in the graph. As defined in the docs.

> A directed graph is strongly connected if there is a path between all
>   pairs of vertices ( nodes ). This algorithms treats the graph as directed, so
>   the direction of the relationship is important and strongly connected
>   compoment exists only if there are relationships between nodes in both
>   direction.

Check out more in the [documentation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-graph-algorithms/#_strongly_connected_components). You will need [neo4j-graph-algorithms](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms/releases).

Example query with writing back the component of the graph to the node.

```
CALL algo.scc('Label','C', {write:true,partitionProperty:'partition'})
YIELD loadMillis, computeMillis, writeMillis, setCount, maxSetSize, minSetSize
```

And then you can find your biggest component with the following query.

```
MATCH (u:Label)
RETURN distinct(u.partition) as partition,count(*) as size_of_partition 
ORDER by size_of_partition DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Appreciate a lot. But I tried and it didn't work. This algorithm can only determine nodes that may make a two-way relationship circle, but it can't make sure every node in this circle are both way connected. For instance, 2 and 4 are not connected in my picture, but when I tried to solve the problem with the graph algorithm, it gives the result 1,2,3,4 which the correct result is 1,2,3 and 1,3,4. Only if 2 and 4 are connected that 1,2,3,4 can meet my need.